# Reduce Array to objects that share certain property: values

Tags: javascript, arrays

**> Everything is in here:** https://jsfiddle.net/qr6hdbx0/

This is my code:

```
var viewport = {
    width: 'undefined',
    height: 'undefined',
    ratio: 1.7
};

var bg_1280x720 = {
    name: 'RZ_BG_1280x720_16-9.png',
    width: '1280',
    height: '720',
    ratio: 1.7
};

var bg_1920x1080 = {
    name: 'RZ_BG_1280x720_16-9.png',
    width: '1280',
    height: '720',
    ratio: 1.7
};

var bg_2000x2000 = {
    name: 'RZ_BG_2000x2000_1-1.png',
    width: '2000',
    height: '2000',
    ratio: 1
};

bgOverlays = [
bg_1280x720,
bg_1920x1080,
bg_2000x2000
]
```

I need a script, that looks at: `viewport.ratio` and then looks at the `.ratio: values` of all the objects in: `bgOverlays` and then creates a new array that has only the objects in it, that are closest to: `viewport.ratio`, in terms of their: `.ratio: value`.

**The expected result in this example would be: newArray [bg_1280x720, bg_1920x1080]**

*I don't know how to do this, I found tutorials that show, how to reduce an array to only one value, that is closest to a given value, but in my case there might be two object in the array that have the same value, and I didn't get it to work… – I would very much appreciate any sort of input. Thank You! – Simon*

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I added that in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qr6hdbx0/ (at the bottom)

Comment: @iota In this case it would be: newArray [bg_1280x720, bg_1920x1080]

Comment: It's better to put all the relevant information in the question.

Comment: @iota Sorry, I had to make manual breaks in the question to show that, and stackoverflow didn't register the breaks… The formatting looked really confusing, that's why.

Comment: @iota I added it to the question.

Comment: You are using the wrong term (reduce), what you need is `filter`.

Comment: @muratgu All right, I will look into this now. :)

Comment: @SimonR. what do you mean exactly by 'Closest' ?

Comment: @AbdelillahAissani All the objects have a property called: `ratio`, `ratio` is always a number and I'm looking for the object(s) that have the closes `ratio: value` – Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @SimonR. what do you mean by 'closest' ? like is '1.7' and '2.5' close ? what is the maxminum gap between two ratios that make you consider them as close ? Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: i guess build in filter method would do just fine.  Whats the issue?

Comment: @AbdelillahAissani Ok so, let's say I have three objects: `obj1.ratio: 1.7` `obj2.ratio: 2.5` `obj3.ratio: 2.5`, and my `viewport.ratio is: 2.4`, then the output should be: `newArray[obj2, obj3]` because it's closest. Maybe not really considered close, but 2.5 is closer to 2.4, than 1.7 is to 2.4. `Edit: No max. gap.`

Comment: @TheFool Hey! I don't have a lot of JS experience, I never worked with .filter() before, but I just heard of it, maybe I can get this to work, but right now, I don't know exactly how…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is to make an array of the `differences` between the `.ratio` values of viewpoint from each object, thus finding the smallest number from that and matching that value with what makes that value in the array of objects.. hope I didn't confuse anyone

```js
var viewport = {
    width: 'undefined',
    height: 'undefined',
    ratio: 1.6
};

var bg_1280x720 = {
    name: 'RZ_BG_1280x720_16-9.png',
    width: '1280',
    height: '720',
  ratio: 1.7
};

var bg_1920x1080 = {
    name: 'RZ_BG_1280x720_16-9.png',
    width: '1280',
    height: '720',
  ratio: 1.7
};

var bg_2000x2000 = {
    name: 'RZ_BG_2000x2000_1-1.png',
    width: '2000',
    height: '2000',
  ratio: 1
};

bgOverlays = [
bg_1280x720,
bg_1920x1080,
bg_2000x2000
]

// I need a script, that looks at: "viewport.ratio" and then looks at the ".ratio: values" of all the objects in: "bgOverlays" and then creates a new array that has only the objects in it, that are closest to: "viewport.ratio", in terms of their: ".ratio: value".

// example:
// viewport.ratio = 1.1     output: newArray[bg_2000x2000]
// viewport.ratio = 2           output: newArray[bg_1280x720, bg_1920x1080]
//well here you go :)

var low=bgOverlays
  .map(a=>Math.abs(a.ratio-viewport.ratio))
  .sort((a,b)=>a-b)[0]

var newArray=bgOverlays
  .filter(a=>Math.abs(a.ratio-viewport.ratio)==low)
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood, you consider -0.1 to 0.1 as close ratio values, I'm gonna use a variable that you can change based on what you consider 'close' values.

```js
var viewport = {
    width: 'undefined',
    height: 'undefined',
    ratio: 1.7
};


const gapThatIConsiderClose = 0.1

var bg_1280x720 = {
    name: 'RZ_BG_1280x720_16-9.png',
    width: '1280',
    height: '720',
    ratio: 1.7
};

var bg_1920x1080 = {
    name: 'RZ_BG_1280x720_16-9.png',
    width: '1280',
    height: '720',
    ratio: 1.7
};

var bg_2000x2000 = {
    name: 'RZ_BG_2000x2000_1-1.png',
    width: '2000',
    height: '2000',
    ratio: 1
};

function closerRatioObjects(){
  return bgOverlays.filter(obj =>  obj.ratio <= viewport.ratio + gapThatIConsiderClose && obj.ratio >= viewport.ratio - gapThatIConsiderClose)

}

bgOverlays = [
bg_1280x720,
bg_1920x1080,
bg_2000x2000
]

console.log(closerRatioObjects())
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted to do… Sorry, If I didn't explain it well enough: There should never be a max. gap, it should always select, whatever is closest, no matter the gap. What TheBombSquad answered is exactly what I needed, still, thank you very much, for your answer!